# Ask for sudo password in Tkinter Mac

Tags: tkinter

I want to execute a command which needs root permission on Mac in Tkinter. I made a popup to ask user's password. How can I check whether it's a correct password or not. Thanks

Comment: Your program shouldn't ask for the `sudo` password. It's very bad practise. But you can test the given password by running a command that you can't if the password was wrong. That way you can observe the changes/program's output. I don't know about Mac but on Ubuntu, you can try reading the raw bytes of a partition. If it succeeds, you have the correct password.

Comment: Why shouldn't I ask for the sudo password

Comment: [python-pam](https://pypi.org/project/python-pam/) module may help.

Comment: Seems like I can't use it on macOS. I used 'pip install python-pam' and in my progam  I used 'import pam' but It said no module named pam

Comment: If you can install the module, then make sure that you use same Python environment as the one you used `pip`.  Actually the package contains only one python script `pam.py`.  May be you can download it directly from the [author site](https://github.com/FirefighterBlu3/python-pam) and put it inside your project directory.

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Type `sudo visudo` in terminal and run.

Then add this `%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

You should enable to get it working.